# What is the best way to implement subscription to a Redis pub sub in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, publish-subscribe

The scenario I am working with is that I have a node.js engine which is receiving web-hook and pubsubhubhub queries from various services. It needs to send the incoming data to Rails for processing and storage.

I'm debating whether to use HTTP callbacks for this on the Rails side, or possibly using Redis Pubsub.

The question is: how do you get Rails to subscribe and listen to Redis? In the examples for Juggernaut, they have it implemented as a loop, but if I put a subscribe loop in a library and initialize it on application load, it blocks the loading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like this?

https://github.com/technoweenie/coffee-resque

I am not sure if it totally fits your problem domain but it seems to have all the right parts, but maybe not in the right order.

Comment: So far what worked is using a Daemon generated from https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator

The other option I thought of is a never-ending background process in rescue or delayed_job that does the subscribe loop on Redis and ActiveRecord manipulation.